# Heading subsubsection without number

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm writing my thesis and, if I insert a `subsubsection`, it appears without number. Therefore, if I refer to it, LaTeX works properly, that is it refers with its true number (i.e. 1.1.1). Why? How can I fix it?

This is a part of my preamble:.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont={bf,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext, empheq, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
```

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`

Comment: Glad you got it working, you may want tocdepth as well, see the referenced question (we'll probably close this one as duplicate as you have confirmed that is the issue)

Comment: Yes, you're right... It's the same question, but asked in another way. This is the reason why I haven't found it before. Sorry!

Comment: That's OK I searched for the answer which is easier, but only if you know the answer:-)